# Vite.js laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

i had problem migrating my laravel to vite.js

this is error message when i run

```
> @ dev D:\Laravel Project\Pos
> vite

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1174
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\Laravel Project\Pos\node_modules\vite\bin\vite.js
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1174:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `vite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andra\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-03T07_16_51_315Z-debug.log
```

how to find which package caused the error ??

Comment: Go to the C:\Users\Andra\AppData\Roaming and delete npm folder and npm-cache. Uninstall nodejs.exe and install last version of nodejs. Run npm install at the root of your laravel projecy in command console.

Comment: Problem solved when update node js to latest version